# Finding all occurances of a substring then deleting a few previous characters up to a previous space in python for all occurances

Tags: python, regex, string

I am having trouble finding out how to do this:

`string = "A'' E'R4 B CR2 G''R8"`

What I want to do is locate all R characters in string, then remove previous characters up to previous space so it looks like this:

`"A'' R4 B R2 R8"`

If anyone can help in what direction to go it would be greatly appreciated, I am new to Python.

Comment: `import re

re.sub('.R', 'R', string)`

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *regular expressions* to solve this problem.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = "A'' E'R4 B CR2 G''R8"
>>> re.sub(r"(?<=\s)\S+(?=R)", "", s)
"A'' R4 B R2 R8"
```

where:

- `(?<=\s)` is a *positive lookbehind* matching a single space character
- `\S+` would match one or more consecutive non-space characters
- `(?=R)` is a *positive lookahead* matching `R` character

You can also not involve any grouping at all: `re.sub(r"\s\S+R", " R", s)`.

Comment: Hi alecxe, thank you so much. I need to study more on this regular expressions syntax. I really appreciate it.